# Add a new branch to pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I've got a data frame whose columns are a multi index with levels

`[['a','b'],['one','two']]`

I have another data frame whose columns are a multi index with levels

`[['c'],['one','two']]`

and I want to merge these multi indices in the natural way to make one with levels

`[['a','b','c'], ['one', 'two']]`

I have tried probably 100 things, from joins, to merges, to set_names, to set_index, to concats and renaming levels and supplying keys, names and labels and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. This seems like a natural thing to want to do. I know there must be a simple way to do this. I'm basically adding a branch to the index tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a concat.

```
In [14]: arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
In [15]: tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
In [16]: index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

In [17]: arrays = [['foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
In [18]: tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
In [19]: index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

In [21]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=index1)
In [23]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=index2)

In [25]: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
Out[25]: 
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux  \
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one   
0       0.192217 -1.392671  1.229953  0.558334 -0.908125  0.934284 -1.240591   
1       0.816492 -0.157933  0.058365 -1.115411 -0.488677  0.204860 -0.268372   
2      -0.160077 -1.825912  0.615397  0.570057 -0.699260 -0.552970  0.056875   
3       1.308078  0.018694  1.047227  1.047585  0.172404  0.861871  0.569599   

first             
second       two  
0      -2.234618  
1      -1.604534  
2       0.151859  
3       0.522803
```

Comment: I realized my issue was a corner-case assignment I was doing was changing the column levels on one of the data frames, which caused concat to do the wrong thing. Thank you for the simple, clear answer.